# Powershell Custom Object Property Value

Tags: powershell

I'm getting a little lost working out the logic for the following script I am working on. I have a list of asset numbers currently stored in a text file as follows:

```
assetlist.txt
111111
222222
333333
444444
```

I am attempting to query Active Directory to verify if the ADComputer object exists. If it is found, I am looking for the ADComputer Name and the DistinguishedName. Here is a sample of my code:

```
$assetList = Get-Content C:\assetlist.txt

Foreach ($asset  in $assetList){
    $adComputer = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '*$assett'" | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName

    $resultTable = @()
    $result = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AssetNumber -Value $asset
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ADName -Value $adComputer.Name
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OU -Value $adComputer.DistinguishedName
    $resultTable += $result

    $resultTable
}
```

I am getting lost in manipulating the results I want to see in my result table. Ultimately I would like to see something along the following lines returned:

```
AssetNumber         ADName                  OU
-----------         ------                  --
111111              111111.mydomain.com     CN=111111,OU=MYOU,DC=mydomain,DC=com
222222              Not Found               Not Found
333333              333333.mydomain.com     CN=333333,OU=MYOU,DC=mydomain,DC=com
```

I know I am missing an IF statement currently to handle if a result is displayed or if a "Not Found" message is recorded in its place. But currently I am stuck even getting the correct values to be returned.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Here are also a few links I've gone over so far for some research:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730946.aspx
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2014/04/19/powershell-tips-for-building-objects-with-custom-properties-and-special-formatting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be near your code but using `[pscustomobject]`

```
$assetList = Get-Content C:\assetlist.txt
$resultTable = @()

Foreach ($asset  in $assetList){
  $adComputer = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '*$asset'"
  If ($adComputer){
    $result = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{AssetNumber = $asset
                                         ADName = $adComputer.Name
                                         OU = $adComputer.DistinguishedName}
  } else {
    $result = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{AssetNumber = $asset
                                         ADName = 'Not Found'
                                         OU = 'Not Found'}
  }
  $resultTable += $result
}
$resultTable
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I think this was most along the lines of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You had an extra `t` after `$asset` in your `Get-ADComputer`. Building your object can be replaced by calculated properties with `Select-Object`.

```
$assetList = Get-Content C:\assetlist.txt

$resultTable = Foreach ($asset in $assetList){
    $adComputer = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '*$asset'" |
        Select-Object @{Name = 'Asset'; Expression = {$Asset}},@{Name = 'ADName'; Expression = {$_.Name}}, @{Name = 'OU'; Expression = {$_.DistinguishedName}}
    if ($null -eq $adComputer) {
        $adComputer = "" | Select-Object @{Name = 'Asset'; Expression = {$Asset}},@{Name = 'ADName'; Expression = {"Not Found"}}, @{Name = 'OU'; Expression = {"Not Found"}}
    }
    $adComputer
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I see now what was wrong.